# Is an Arduino bluetooth-to-Wifi relay possible for using with Beacons?

Tags: bluetooth, arduino, wifi, beacon

My knowledge in both bluetooth beacons and Arduino is limited at this point.

This is for an indoor positioning system I'm thinking to develop. Is it possible to create an Arduino board where the BT module receives a BT beacon ping with the Beacon ID, and then relays this data to a Wifi module on the same board, to then send it out to a server/local server of some sort?

Is this feasible? Or is it even possible the receive the ID of the beacon using Arduino?

I've attached an image of what I was thinking of:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is absolutely possible.  I have done the same with a Raspberry Pi.  I am not an expert on programming the Arduino but I know for sure that both parts (beacon detection and decoding) and calling a web service over WiFi are possible with the Arduino.